# Kill and restart a program with a single command

Tags: command-line, bash, autokey

Autokey-QT sometimes gets stuck. It hasn't crashed, it's still running, but it's done half of a script and then stopped for some reason. I haven't been able to figure out why because I can't duplicate the issue at will. The only way I've found to continue is to kill the program in System Monitor and re-launch.

How could I do that in a bash script? The goal being to create a keyboard shortcut that will do this action.

Comment: First, make sure you're using AutoKey 0.96.0. It's better behaved than older versions. Second, make sure you haven't coded any infinite loops in your scripts - especially tight loops. If those don't fix it, then go with @huha 's answer or use `pkill autokey && autokey-qt &`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have only one instance of it running on your machine:

`killall autokey-qt && autokey-qt myarg1 myarg2`

The caveat is that, since it's a GUI automation tool, it's probably waiting for some GUI program to get finished with a task, and just killing it will probably leave that GUI program in a very undefined state. That might create more problems than you are trying to solve with that impatient approach. Maybe first find out where it hangs and what the cause of that is.

Comment: There can be only one! ;) If you run AutoKey an additional time it tells the first instance to display the main menu and then exits.